# Как выполнить скрипт, заданный строкой?

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли каким-либо образом при выдаче информации в блок id1 выдать информацию и в другой блок id2 через js-код  в строке string1?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  var string2='string2';

  // var string1='<scri' +'pt>document. getElementById("id2").HTML=string2;</scri'+ 'pt>'; //  не работает
  var string1='document. getElementById("id2").innerHTML=string2';  // работает

function f() {
document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML=string1;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="id1"> </div>
<div id="id2"> </div>
<input  type=button   value='Press' onClick='f()'>
</body>
</html>
```

А вот  такой вариант (только правильный) возможен?

```
 document.getElementById('id1').innerHTML='Содержимое для id1 <scri' +'pt>document. getElementById("id2").innerHTML="Содержимое для id2";</scri'+ 'pt>';
```

Т.е. одной командой при выдаче в id1  меняется и блок id1, и другой блок id2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через DOM:

```
function f() {
    var scr = document.createElement( "script" );
    scr.textContent = string1;
    documend.head.appendChild( scr );
};
```

Через eval:

```
function f() {
    eval( string1 );
};
```

Comment: через `new Function()`:

    new Function(string).call(this);